# Ubuntu ssh-ing Ubuntu on home network

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I have a laptop (Ubuntu, wifi) and PC (Ubuntu, Ethernet) connected to my home router.

I'd like to be able to ssh from laptop to PC to copy and run executables.

I don't need a gui, just running htop and gdb at most.

How simple is this to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple.

1. Install an ssh server on the PC:

   ```
   sudo apt install openssh-server
   ```
2. Open the SSH port in the firewall (if you have the firewall enabled):

   ```
   sudo ufw allow ssh
   ```
3. Find the IP address of the PC

   ```
   ip a
   ```
4. On the laptop, type

   ```
   ssh <username_on_pc>@<ip_address_of_pc>
   ```

   type "yes" in response to prompt and enter the password for the user on the PC.

You now have an SSH connection!